# Get parent id in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, html

How can i get Parent Div id (id="parent") when i click into the input text?
Here is my sample html code:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
     <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the string "parent" or just the div two levels higher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$("input.form-control").click(function(){
  
  var parentId= $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  alert(parentId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
     <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.form-control').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```